# retrieve data from APi and display using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
for(var u in jsonData){
    User user =User(u['id'],u['email'],u['firstName'],u['lastName'],u['avatar']);
    users.add(user);
}
```

Comment: what is your error

Comment: What even is your question?

Comment: the problem with the for loop it conceder is as unused and this kind of comment "Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>') "

Answer (score 0):

> Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable')

This is likely because your `foreach` is expecting something that is iterable, but your `jsonData` object is not iterable, it is a map. My guess is that your JSON looks something like:

```
{
    something: [
        { id: x, email: y, ...},
        ...
    ]
}
```

In which case you may need to use `jsonData['something']` in the foreach, because you need to enumate an array and not an object.